# Finding conan package folder from conanfile.py

Tags: python, cmake, conan

We're using `conan v1.59` in our project (forced to as that's client's setup). It's a project in C, the build tool is `CMake`. This project has several dependencies. We're utilizing `conanfile.py` for building and packaging artifacts.

Let's say, `ch-common` is a requirement for this project. It's mentioned in `conanfile.py` as follows:

```
def requirements(self):
    ...
    self.requires("ch-common/0.0.10@x/y")
    ...
```

The development environment is `Debian Linux`. `ch-common` is downloaded and CMake can find it, code compiles properly. `ch-common` only has a header file `cr_def.h`.

The artifact of our project is a library. Internally the library uses an enum in `cr_def.h`. The users of our project (those who'll be calling various functions of the library) will also need the `cr_def.h` because in many APIs defined in the library the enum is used as parameter.

We have a `package()` in `conanfile.py` to package the artifacts:

```
def package(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.install()
    self.copy("*.h", dst="include/project/", src="include/public/", keep_path=False)
```

We'd like to copy `cr_def.h` in the `package()` like others.

How can `cr_def.h` be referred in the `package()` without hardcoded fixed path? We **don't want** to do something like:

```
self.copy("cr_def.h",
          dst="include/project/",
          src=os.path.expanduser('~') + "/.conan/data/ch-common/0.0.10/x/y/package/<hash>/include/",
          keep_path=False)
```

Is there any variable holding the package location? Is there any better way to copy `cr_def.h`?

We can't ask our library users to include `ch-common` in their project - that's a client requirement.

Comment: *It's a project in C.* Why do you tag [tag:C++]?

Comment: @273K: My problem has nothing to do with programming language. I've tagged both C and C++ because people using Conan are most likely to use C and/or C++. I wanted more audience.

Comment: *I wanted more audience* This is your mistake. Your simple question is how to add a file to a conan package. `src` path likely depends on the cmake config. Hence, you better tag [tag:cmake].

Comment: Sorry, it is not very clear what you want. You want to store a copy of the *dependency* header file in the consumer package? The way to access dependencies is ``self.dependencies["ch-common"].package_folder`` (or other accessors like ``.cpp_info.includedirs``. Probably needs more elaboration, this would be better for discussion as a github issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues